# Add button click event to button control generated from database

Tags: asp.net

I have a Test.aspx page which is inheriting from a master page. I am populating the controls contents from database for the Test.aspx page.

I am fetching the entire string containing all the controls content from database and using Page.ParseControl method to parse the input string to control and then adding the control to the content placeholder.

The string that is fetched from database contains the following button control.

The above button control is rendered to the UI but when i am trying to click the button , then no button click event is triggered.

Can any one help me out to resolve this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: At what stage you call _Page.ParseControl()_, at PageLoad ? What is your code for binding event-handlers ?

Comment: I am calling the Page.PaeseControl in the Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your controls need to be created before postback data is processed for the events to fire. You can't recreate the controls in page_load or later they must be created earlier in the page lifecycle. We used to create the child controls in the construtor of the containing page (or custom control) and then the events would work.

Comment: How about adding the control in Page_PreInit()?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below

```
Button btn = (Button)Page.ParseControl("<asp:button text='Click here!' runat='server' />");
if(btn != null)
{
   btn.Click += new EventHandler(BtnClick); 
}
void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   //do something
}
```

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: Button btn = (Button)Page.ParseControl("<asp:button text='Click here!' runat='server' />"); is giving the following error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.